# Transform integral bounds when changing to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

When transforming an integral from euclidean to polar coordinates we have this for example:
$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x,y)dxdy = \int^\infty_{0}\int^{2\pi}_0f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)rd\theta dr
$$
I can plug in some functions and evaluate to prove this holds, but I can't think of a reason or intuition why the RHS is not
$$
\int_\infty^{0}\int^{2\pi}_0f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)rd\theta dr
$$
or
$$
\int^\infty_{0}\int_{2\pi}^0f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)rd\theta dr
$$
where one of the bounds is flipped, I know this would result a negation and break the equality, but why is it that integrating from the origin in polar coordinates corresponds to integrating from negative to positive infinity in the euclidean space?

Comment: Either your integrals or your differentials are in the wrong order (they are mismatched). It should be $\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} f \, r \, d\theta \, dr$ or else $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty f \, r \, dr \, d\theta$.

Comment: @Nick You're right, (edited now), but that's not important concerning my question.